# When is it useful creating multiple consumers from a single session in Jms?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I read activemq's doc for multiple consumers:http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html

It says `The JMS contract is that only 1 session is used by one thread at once - which if you're using consumers means that only 1 consumer can receive messages at once if using the same session.`, so we should always create multiple sessions when need to have multiple consumers.

But the api of JMS do have methods to create multiple consumers from a single session, and it seems to work fine.

I wonder if where is some special conditions that multiple consumers from one session has its worth? Or is that just a useless feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue here is one of concurrency.  If you create multiple consumers from a single session and never use those consumers concurrently then you won't have a problem.

Off the top of my head I can't think of a specific use-case for multiple consumers created from a single session and used serially, but that doesn't mean a legitimate use-case doesn't exist.